# How can I print all files in all projectiles?

Tags: projectile

I'm trying to print out all files in all projectiles

```
(let ((files (seq-filter (lambda (b) (string-match "org$" b))
               (mapcan (lambda (root)
                     (mapcar (lambda (f)
                           (concat root f))
                         (projectile-project-files root)))
                   projectile-known-projects))))

  (message files)
  )
```

, but it throws an error

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp ("~/foo.org ...))
  (let ((files (seq-filter #'(lambda (b) (string-match "org$" b)) (mapcan #'(lambda (root) (mapcar ... ...)) projectile-known-projects)))) (message files))
  elisp--eval-last-sexp(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  funcall-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil)
  command-execute(eval-last-sexp)
```

I'm not really sure what stringp is here.

Comment: You should adjust the question so that it is about the error message, rather than about projectile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answers make clear, you are passing a list to `message` which wants a string instead.

But there is no need to use `message` at all. Try this:

```el
(let ((files (seq-filter (lambda (b) (string-match "org$" b))
                         (mapcan
                          (lambda (root)
                            (mapcar
                             (lambda (f)
                               (concat root f))
                             (projectile-project-files root)))
                          projectile-known-projects))))

  files)
```

Here `files` is the value of the `let` expression. When you evaluate it in your `*scratch*` buffer or in IELM, the value is printed out in the buffer itself (that's the `print` part of a REPL (`read-eval-print loop`). If you evaluate it with `C-x C-e`, the value is printed in the Echo Area. In either case, you only care about the value and this is the most direct way of getting it.

Answer (score 1):

`stringp` is a function that checks whether the argument is a string. Since `'("~foo.org")` is a list, it means you need a string where you have a list.

In this case, your logic is correct, but `message` is the problem. `message` can only take a string argument, and otherwise operates like the `format` function. Knowing this, we can use the following interpolation:

`(message "%s" files)`

And Bob's your uncle.

Comment: `%s` is good *if* the second argument is a string: it avoids misinterpreting things like `%` signs in the string, but if you are trying to pass a Lisp data structure to message, `%S` is better IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the error message again:

```lisp
(wrong-type-argument stringp ("~/foo.org" ...))
```

This means that you called a function, but gave it the wrong type of argument. It wanted a string (technically any object for which the `stringp` predicate returns `t`), but you gave it a list whose first element was a string. `stringp` doesn’t return `t` for a list of strings, because a list of strings is not a string.

You tried to pass this list to `message`, but if you check the documentation for it (using `C-h f`), you will see that it takes a format string followed by any number of arguments:

```
(message FORMAT-STRING &rest ARGS)
```